# What is VLC subtitle position keyboard shortcut

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, vlc-media-player, subtitles

What are the keyboard shortcuts to move subtitles in VLC up or down?

Comment: I don't believe there are keyboard shortcuts for that at present.

Comment: You know the process to do it without a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: There is an offset option in configuration but it takes a lot of trial and error to guess the right number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least on VLC 2.1.6, you can set the shortcut under the `Tools->Hotkeys` menu (with `Simple` `Show settings`). However, cumbersome enough, shifting the subtitle position doesn't come into effect until you restart VLC, which makes the shortcut rather useless, speeding up the trial-error process thought.

I was looking to set overtitles because the video I was seeing had embedded subtitles and I noticed that you can set the offset to a high value (say 1000) and vlc will place the subtitles as high as possible.

EDIT: As reported by the OP, at least from VLC 2.2.1, the subtitle shift is instantaneous.

Comment: In my vlc version the position is changed at once. I will now have to look into http://askubuntu.com/questions/284709/how-to-show-subtitles-under-the-video-in-vlc to show them even lower.

Comment: oh great! What version is that?

Comment: 2.2.1 on Win x64

Comment: I think this answer addresses subtitle position in time, not on screen.

Comment: No. I'm talking about sxreen position.

Comment: 3.0.16 on Mac - have to restart each time for it to take effect.